# catch consecutive error in .net c # using try catch

Tags: c#, try-catch, counter

I have a block of code that is executed N times within a foreach loop, and I need to detect if an error occurs more than 5 times in a row. I set a counter but I don't know how to detect if the increase was continuous or intermittently. And I need to stop the process only when those errors are continuous.

The code.

```
        int consecutiveError = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                //......
                //fail
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (consecutiveError == 5)
                stopProccess();
        }
```

Comment: If there is no error, set the counter to 0. But from the looks of it, your foreach statement will be terminated on any exception. Probably rethink how you are coding this

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances (i.e. you are not expecting it to happen).  If you ARE  expecting these errors then I'd suggest exceptions are not the correct method.

Comment: You mean if faill more then 5 time continues then and only stop Process?

Comment: Exceptions are for things you can't check for, like out of memory, database connection failed. or looking up a record that you have the primary key for, but it no longer exists.  If you use exception handling for general purpose things like divide by zero errors, or things you can legitimately check for, then IMO you are using them wrong.

Comment: @Neil There is a confusion with exceptions: they are not for exceptionnal circumstances. This word in computing has the meaning of "*An interruption in normal processing*". They are raised when an error or to interrupt a processing, and tell callers why instead a boolean & global artifact for data. Reducing exceptions to errors is not understanding internal operation of CPU exceptions and the logic of this control of execution flow, and thus it is to deprive oneself of taking advantage of that. Exceptions is to interrupt the standard flow to do a special case. Errroring is only half the power.

Comment: Do you want to simply ignore Exceptions 1-4 or at least log them or put the items in a dead-letter queue or something?

Comment: @Fildor OP wants to count the errors and trap them and continue the loop until there are 5 consecutive iteration with error and at that point stop and do something, or else act as if nothing had happened. Such a scheme makes it possible not to overload the system and make you wait a long time while giving a chance to preview. Here errors are accepted according to the scheme indicated and simply put to trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
  int errorCount = 0;
  foreach ( var item in collection )
  {
    try
    {
      //Code ......
      //fail

      //At end of code
      errorCount = 0;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
      errorCount++;
      if ( errorCount > 5 )
      {
        stopProccess();
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Off by one, I think. Doesn't this only stop the process on 6th exception in a row? Sugesting `if ( errorCount >= 5 )`

Comment: Right, but requirement is more then 5 so    errorCount > 5

Comment: This is bad usage of exception handling, I would advise to not follow this. One, you should *not* be using try/catch blocks to depict code flow. Two, you're throwing again inside the nested catch, why, what are you trying to bubble up?

Comment: @zaggler ... bad or good, depend on application requirements... catching exceptions is meant to prevent them to escalate and crash the application (or at least avoid state corruption) AND to log diagnostic information. In this specific case, throwing the last one will determine loss of information (what about the previous 5 ?): better store them and throw an AggregateException instead. Is responsibility of the OP to determine whether the enumeration can recover during the first 5 exceptions and whether discarding 5 exceptions is good or bad decision.